# JavaScript / Ajax - Check if data on another page is different

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page called getlastupdate.php it holds the last date & time someone has updated a database, when you visit that page you would get something like this:

```
2013-07-23 10:43:37
```

What I'm trying to do is when I load my main page I want javascript to get the above date and time and store it in a var and then using ajax keep checking the page 'getlastupdate.php' for the date/time and compare it with the var, if the date/time are the same don't do anything but if they are not then alert with a message and then update the var to the last date/time.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var comper;
$.get('getlastupdate.php', function(comperNow) {  // comperNow is the latest date/time var
// remember the date/time in var called: comper
comper = comperNow;
}
)

function mycode() {
// keep checking this page for the date/time
$.get('getlastupdate.php', function(comperNow) {
// if comper is not the same as comperNow
if (comper!=comperNow){
// show a message to the visitor
alert('New Info Added');
// and update comper to show the date/time from comperNow
comper = comperNow;
}
}
)

tid = setTimeout(mycode, 2000); // repeat myself
}
function abortTimer() { // to be called when you want to stop the timer
clearTimeout(tid);
}

            </script>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is the problem though?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem, it is an interpretation of flawed logic.  What specifically is the problem? Does it throw an error? Does it never clear the timer?

Comment: You're storing data in local variables and then referencing them out of scope... Use `window.comper` or something.

Comment: with your if statement (if (comper<>comperNow)), do you mean (!=) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code worked for me. I think the biggest problem was the use of setTimeout instead of setInterval.

```
var comper;
function checkComper() {
  var onResponse = function(comperNow) {  // comperNow is the latest date/time var
    //check if comper has been set / first time method is called
    if (comper === undefined) {
      comper = comperNow;
      return;
    }

    if (comper !== comperNow) {
      // show a message to the visitor
      alert('New Info Added');
      // and update comper to show the date/time from comperNow
      comper = comperNow;
    }
  };
  $.get('getlastupdate.php', onResponse);
}

var tid = setInterval(checkComper, 2000); // repeat myself
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `var comper;` Global
Like this:

```
var comper;
$.get('getlastupdate.php', function(comperNow) {  // comperNow is the latest date/time var
// remember the date/time in var called: comper
comper = comperNow;
}
```